# Mutating request.base_url in Flask

Tags: python, ssl, request, flask

I have a Flask application behind a Load balance that terminates SSL. I have code that "detects" when SSL is being used and mutates the request object:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    x_forwarded_proto = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto')
    if  x_forwarded_proto == 'https':
        request.url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
        request.url_root = request.url_root.replace('http://', 'https://')
        request.host_url = request.host_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
```

I then have a blueprint view function:

```
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, url_prefix='/admin')
@admin.route('/login')
def login():
    print request.url
```

The output of this function is (when I go to /admin/login) is always http:// instead of https:// (even though it should have been mutated in the `before_request` function.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you checked if the if x_forwarded_proto == 'https' evaluates to true ?

Comment: @codegeek It does evaluate to true, see my solution.

Comment: This is rather the wrong approach, just use the `ProxyFix` middleware, see [X-Forwarded-Proto and Flask](//stackoverflow.com/q/23347387), and the WSGI environment will be fixed up for you before Flask even begins creating a `request` object from it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out `request` is  a proxied object. I'm not sure of the internals but it's "reset" on each import. I solved the issue by subclassing `Request`

```
class ProxiedRequest(Request):
    def __init__(self, environ, populate_request=True, shallow=False):
        super(Request, self).__init__(environ, populate_request, shallow)
        # Support SSL termination. Mutate the host_url within Flask to use https://
        # if the SSL was terminated.
        x_forwarded_proto = self.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto')
        if  x_forwarded_proto == 'https':
            self.url = self.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
            self.host_url = self.host_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
            self.base_url = self.base_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
            self.url_root = self.url_root.replace('http://', 'https://')

app = Flask(__name__);
app.request_class = ProxiedRequest
```

Comment: This should be added to Flask's default Request class. Thanks for sharing it with us.

Comment: It seems this has been added to flask. I am using flask==0.10.1

Comment: Looks like the functionality is available in as a [fixer in Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/contrib/fixers/#werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix).

Comment: I am using flask 2.0.1 and still found this snippet useful! i wonder why this hasn't been integrated yet.