# X-Forwarded-Proto and Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, werkzeug

I have precisely the same problem described in [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840051/mutating-request-base-url-in-flask). The answer to that question is a nice work around but I don't understand the fundamental problem. Terminating SSL at the load balancer and using HTTP between the load balancer and web/app servers is very common. What piece of the stack is not respecting the X-Forwarded-Proto? Is it werkzeug? Flask? uwsgi?

In my case I'm using an AWS ELB (which sets X-Forwarded-Proto) => Nginx (which forwards along X-Forwarded-Proto to uwsgi). But in the python app I have to subclass Flask Request as described in the question I referenced above.

Since this is such a common deployment scenario, it seems that there should be a better solution. What am I missing?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are missing the [`ProxyFix()` middleware component](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/middleware/proxy_fix/#module-werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix). See the Flask [Proxy Setups documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/deploying/proxy_fix/).

There is no need to subclass anything; simply add this middleware component to your WSGI stack:

```
# Werkzeug 0.15 and newer
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1)
```

If you have Flask installed, you have Werkzeug too, but do pin the version to >=0.15 to get the updated version of `ProxyFix` (Flask 1.1.0 and newer already use that version).

This component [sets the WSGI scheme from the X-Forwarded-Proto header](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/129b3fa0041b874951ce89cbc0a7a6d6e8944414/src/werkzeug/middleware/proxy_fix.py#L165-L228). Do read the Flask documentation I linked you to above about trusting headers and about customising the middleware to your specific situation. Above, I’ve configured it to only look at `X-Forwarded-Proto`, but the component can handle other `X-Forwarded-*` configurations too.

The default is to trust one level of `X-Forwarded-For`, add `x_for=0` to the keyword arguments if you want to disable this.

Also note that the functionality of the `ProxyFix` middleware has been expanded quite significantly in Werkzeug 0.15; in addition to `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `-For`, and `-Host`, the `X-Forwarded-Port` and `-Prefix` headers are also consulted, all headers support multiple values.

Comment: This is great information!  But I'm still curious about "What piece of the stack is not respecting the X-Forwarded-Proto? Is it werkzeug? Flask? uwsgi?"  Or is that the X-Forwarded-Proto header shouldn't be "respected" unless we specify that there is a trusted proxy that is writing those headers?

Comment: @NealGokli: the latter. Anyone out on the internet could set that header..