# jinja request.url_root giving me http instead of https

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Using this

request.url_root+ attributes["footer"]["district_link"]

in jinja on a page that is https:// gives me a url that has http:// which is causing problems. Is there a way to use this request that preserves this so it will be http:// on a page that uses http and https on a page that uses https?

The backend is using flask if that is relevant here

Answer (score 0):

Is your app proxied behind something like nginx?

If so you will need to use something like [ProxyFix](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/contrib/fixers/) to add headers that include this information.

You can read more about proxy configuration in [the flask docs on proxy setups](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups).

Once you have ProxyFix working you can make use of the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header (for example). There's some more helpful info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23504684/9794932).

Comment: It does use nginx!

Comment: @lathomas64 great, I've added some more to the answer that should help you get going.

Comment: The problem was solved by someone else automatically redirecting to https so I Won't be spending time looking into getting this working but hopefully it helps someone else down the line.